# Show images from perticular folder in iOS

Tags: ios, image, flutter

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_gallery to show images stored in the particular folder but it is showing all images from the gallery is there any way that I can use it to show from a particular folder only

Answer (score 1):

If you want specific directory location image then use `ext_storage` package. You can get all the files of the specific folder. You just have to separate it by extension. Please look at the code below so you can get idea. the code is same as shown in library.

```
void _example1() async {
  var path = await ExtStorage.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  print(path);  // /storage/emulated/0
}
```